# Trying to get a diagonal sum

Tags: python, python-2.7, sum, diagonal

Trying to get the sum diagonally in #7 of the lists that #6 creates. So say the list was this `[[2,3,1],[1,1,1],[5,6,4]]` the sum would be 2+1+4

```
#6

def randomlists(s):
    b=s
    list1 = []
    while s>0:
        sublist = []
        for x in range(0,b):
            sublist.append(randrange(-100,101))
        list1.append(sublist)
        s-=1
    return list1
#print(randomlists(5))
#7

def diagonalsum(x):
    a=randomlists(x)
    count=0
    print (a)
    for b in a:
        while count<x:
            d=a[0]
            b=a[1]
            c=a[2]
            print (a[(count)])
            count+=1
        return d+b+c
print (diagonalsum(3))
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the matrix is square, this is a standard solution using a loop:

```
def diagonalsum(m):
  count = 0
  for i in xrange(0, len(m)):
    count += m[i][i]
  return count
```

... Which can be written in a more concise way, by using generator expressions and the `sum` function:

```
def diagonalsum(m):
    return sum(m[i][i] for i in xrange(len(m)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy.trace: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html. It returns the sum along diagonals of the array.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[2,3,1],[1,1,1],[5,6,4]])

print(M.trace())

#7
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the diagonal elements you take the first in the first row, the second in the second row ... the nth in the nth row.

```
def diagonalsum(x):
    a = randomlists(x)
    return sum(row[i] for i, row in enumerate(a))
```

The not so concise alternative that uses a *normal* for loop reads

```
def diagonalsum(x):
    a = randomlists(x)
    result=0
    for i, row in enumerate(a):
        result += row[i]
    return result
```

Comment: I am unclear as to what row and enumerate are, we haven't learned that is it built into python or are those just variables in your program?

Comment: Enumerate is a python built in function see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate. The term inside the call to `sum` is a so called generator expression that is kind of a for loop that generates a list. `row` is a temporary variable that is set to inner lists of `a` one after the other while you loop over it.